# SSRS cascading parameters: child parameters' default 'All' value drops to blank after user changes parent parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, mdx, rdl, cascading

I have a big bunch of cascading parameters in my rdl report with default value 'All' everywhere. But all children go blank after user changes some parent parameter, and then he has to choose 'All' value from drop-down list for each of child parameters manually. This is pretty annoying staff. How can I force report to fix default 'All' value for child parameters, despite of any changes to parent parameter?

Comment: So, basically you don;t want the child parameters to refresh when the parent parameter change? That's against the concept of cascading parameters. I don't think you need cascading parameters then.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti, basically I do need cascading child parameters, and every time parent changes - I do refresh children with 'All' dimension member included always. And I need this 'All' default value not to go blank after parent parameter changes, I need to keep it selected, by default

Comment: `and every time parent changes - I do refresh children with 'All' dimension member included always...`What kind of cascading is that??

Comment: Cascading is said to happen when the child's parameter's value changes depending on the value of parent parameter. This is handled almost always in the datasets of the respective parameters. If you are interested in default selection of "All", you would need to play around with your datasets.

Comment: Oh, man... Here is a simple calendar sample: we have 2 prams 'Year' (default 2015) and 'Quarter' (default 'All', list: All, 2015.Q1, 2015.Q2, 2015.Q3, 2015.Q4). Now user changes Year to 2014, child Quarter parameter refreshes it's list to: All, 2014.Q1, 2014.Q2, 2014.Q3, 2014.Q4. But report drops Quarter's default value from 'All' to blank, but I want it to stay!! God, bless me

Comment: You should probably edit your question and add this description. Your question lacks clarity.

Comment: Have you considered, un-checking the "Allow blank values" option for the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found decision for my child parameter go-blank problem. In the Report Parameters dialog just print to the 'non-queried' field default value in quotes. For example, in case of olap data source: print

```
="[Calendar].[Quarter].&[All]"
```

instead of:

```
[Calendar].[Quarter].&[All]
```

After this Quarter child cascading parameter will not lose it's default value 'All' when user chooses another Year. Nuts!

Comment: Hi Globe, I am working on the same issue and can't find a proper solution. I didn't understand your answer, so please elaborate your answer with more detailed example if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do by keeping the default value to "All". That is for only the first time the report is rendered. Once you change the parent parameter, the child value is refreshed and then it starts looking towards "Available values" set.

So, whatever values are coming from the dataset which is the source of Available Values, will be considered to populate the child parameter then. So only way you can still have an "All" *still*, is to modify the dataset. We could probably help you further if you could share the MDX queries for the parameters, or even you could give it as shot.

Comment: The dataset is fine, I've found a fix for my problem. Look my Answer. It works. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion and time